# Intel Wireless Adapter suddenly not working - Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, drivers, uefi, iwlwifi

I've been now trying to find a solution to my problem for an absurd amount of hours and days.
Hopefully some of you can help me with those log messages:

```
02:54:39 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
02:54:39 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
02:54:39 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2, CPU2 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC9381428 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC6AF39FF | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC8B350F8 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x44E089D5 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD49BF01B | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBC56634F | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9A15BFFC | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x654FBC66 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
02:54:38 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
```

```
03:11:48 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
```

Both, the Bluetooth and the WiFi died after the laptop was on airplane-mode for some hours. I've been running Ubuntu 19.04 during that time. And no updates have been done, which confuses me the most.

Since then I reinstalled the OS, got back on Ubuntu 18.04 and even got a solo Windows 10 installation, to figure out if I could find better resources with those error codes and software from the manufacturer.

The adapter is definitely recognized (lspci), but is not being initialized. There are no blocks(rfkill), and downgrading the kernel, was unfortunately also not successful.
Secure Boot is disabled. PTT enabled. I'm running now on Ubuntu 19.10. 
Intel-microcode and intel-firmware are updated.

```
dmesg | grep wifi
[    4.117702] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.144852] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.144855] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    4.145339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.231252] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9460, REV=0x318
[    4.239550] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.240610] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    4.245904] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    4.245911] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    4.245926] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    4.245936] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x654FB46F | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    4.245946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9A15BFBC | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    4.245957] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3456E35F | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    4.245966] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD7BBE20B | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    4.245976] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x40E081E5 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    4.245986] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC8A350F2 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    4.245996] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCEAE31FB | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    4.246006] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC9381428 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    4.246016] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.246059] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.246137] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    4.246209] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    4.246404] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2, CPU2 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2
[    4.246416] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    4.246421] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[    4.492428] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    4.505614] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

Side note: I don't know if the information is beneficial to you guys,but as I had Windows installed, I couldn't update or reinstall any drivers for the adapter, because 'system policies prohibiting an install' for the adapter. It was stuck on the device manager with 'Error Code 10' because of an outdated driver, which is provided with the Windows-Install-iso.

I really appreciate any ideas, because I'm absolutely clueless at this point, thanks in advance

Comment: obligatory xkcd https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with the wifi adapter being recognized (via lspci) but I found no way of initializing it. While my error output was a bit different, it has lead me to the [Archlinux Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249358), and from there, the [linked comment for an Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1836986/comments/14) fixed my issue:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0
```

In my case, the kernel update plus a reboot had happened a few days earlier, and the wifi adapter stopped working after one of the wake-ups from suspend (not even the first one) which made this seem to happen out of the blue.

Disclaimer: I have no clue what this command does, so if you are afraid of running unknown commands found on the internet, I'd recommend to not do this.

I'd rather have just commented on your question, but I lack reputation to do so.

EDIT 2020-01-25: While my answer from two months ago worked fine for me for a while, in the meantime, I came to the conclusion that the root cause lies in the suspend which seems to break something once in a while.
So a shutdown and removal of power source (incl. battery) before rebooting made the wifi adapter run again without any error messages. And this is more trustworthy a fix than running commands one does not understand.

Comment: good tip to shutdown and remove bat